# Call to a member function getAll($request) on null construct in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I created a controller class with `construct` and `get` methods:

```
use App\Repositories\Backend\myObj\myObjContract;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller {

  protected $myObj;

  public function construct(myObjContract $myObj) {
    $this->myObj = $myObj;
  }
  public function get(Request $request) {
    $this->myObj->getAll($request);
  }
}
```

getAll() is already declared in contract and also defined in the eloquent file.

But I got an error:

> Call to a member function getAll($request) on null

Can anyone help to solve above error?

Comment: How does your `myObjContract` class look like?

Comment: you create a parmeterize constructor, so you should add the code snippet how you are creating the object of this class and also code for your `myObjContract ` class

Comment: Doest `myObjContract` have a function `getAll`?

Comment: 1. Shouldn't `construct` be the magic method `__construct`? 2. Try `myObjContract::all()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you trying to do but if you did not create "getAll" you maybe want $request->all();

Comment: getAll() already declared  in  contract and also defined in eloquent file.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the constructor method is named `__construct` (with the two underscores). PHP essentially interpreted your `construct` method as a regular class method, so when you called `getAll()`, it was on a null variable.

```
use App\Repositories\Backend\myObj\myObjContract;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    protected $myObj;

    public function __construct(myObjContract $myObj)
    {
        $this->myObj = $myObj;
    }

    public function get(Request $request)
    {
        $this->myObj->getAll($request);
    }
}
```